# Facebook Debug Result Suspended

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I'm using Facebook Sharing Debug (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing) to check my domain (http://duniakulinerbandung.com) but the result is 302

This is the screenshoot:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fHnH.png)

It's says

```
Inferred Property : The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Missing Properties : The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
```

When i check my website, the og:image, og:url and other has setted up.

How to fix this issue? i Can't share my website on facebook

Comment: Note that it shows an IPv6 address for your server, so double-check that is actually correct. Facebook prefers v6 over v4 if available, and this often trips people up when their setup for v6 is not actually correct, but no one noticed so far, because most "surfing users" are still on v4 connections. If that's not it, seeing as it redirects to an "Account Suspended" page, talk to your hoster whether they have anything set up that might block requests by "bots".

Comment: @CBroe so my problem is my v6 setup is not actually correct?

Comment: I said that you should check whether that's it ...